# SPSite for Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, spsite

newbie question,

I have an office 365 E4 plan in the office and have been playing around with SharePoint.

I reached a point where i need to code a few things.

Can i use powershell and SPSite to connect to SharePoint online, ie not a local farm.

I have successful used SPOSite but cant seem to be able to use SPSite.

thanks,
Alex

Comment: Are you using the powershell cmdlet for SharePoint online?

Comment: SPOSite means site collection? SPSite means sub site?

Comment: As far as I understand the functionality of SPOSite is very limited vs SPSite. .?

Comment: In the poershell cmdlet of SharePoint oline, SPOSite means the site collection, the root one. I don't find the SPSite term in this powershell cmd. If you don't understand the term site collection, you should look into doc of sharepoint first

Comment: I think you're missing my point. The question is, the following, there are two cmd "types" the "SPO" and "SP".

Comment: "SPO" is for example get-SPOSite while "SP" is get-SPSite

Comment: The "SPO" cmd's are a lot less than the "SP" ones. I would have liked to be able to use the "SP" cmd's on a sharepoint online account, something which unfortunately i don't believe is possible

Comment: Did you try this: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/technet/en-us/office/media/windowspowershell/windowspowershellcommandbuilder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short version is no, you can't. The "O" in "SPO" is for "Online". The [SPO- family of cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161362%28v=office.15%29.aspx) are for SharePoint Online, and not all the same functionality is exposed in the online version as on-premises.

Often, however, there are alternatives depending on the specific scenario you're trying to enable.

Comment: By the way one of the things i wanted to do and thus the SPSite cmdlet is this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/4966/using-powershell-make-the-sharepoint-choice-field-default-va.aspx